# Cassandra requesting data from a node which is down?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, consistency

Setup:
2 Nodes, Ec2Snitch 
1 Node UP       54.1xx.1xx.1xx  
1 Node Down     54.1xx.2xx.1xx [deliberately]

Keyspace NetworkTopology Replication Factor of 2
(both the nodes have data)

Now I tested read with Consistency level ONE.

Im getting "All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 54.1xx.2xx.1xx: Host considered as DOWN. See innerErrors."
 Getting this for the node that is down.

Why am i getting this exception? Shouldn't Cassandra service all requests from Node which is UP automatically? [I was expecting Cassandra to handle it.]

Or should we be dealing with a node which is DN (Down Normal)
How do i deal with this?

If i manually make the Down node Up, I get all the responses else i get the above error for the first 1/4 of total requests.

Comment: What client are you using and which nodes is the client aware of?

Comment: Im using DataStax Node.js Driver for Cassandra`
 var reader = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: ['54.1xx.1xx.1xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com', '54.1xx.1xx.1xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'],
    queryOptions: {
        consistency: cassandra.types.consistencies.any,
    },
 policies: {loadBalancing: new cassandra.policies.loadBalancing.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(localDc, remoteNodes)},
});`

Comment: You can check after client.connect which are the nodes discovered and to check if there is a problem when discovering: `client.hosts.keys()`

Comment: hosts.keys() give me both the ip address.

Comment: You can enable logging to see what is going on: https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#logging and err `innerErrors` will give you a detail of what failed per node.

Comment: while connecting the logs mark the private ip of the down node. (reader.connect). then on every(first 1/4th request) reader.execute() it tries to connect -> it sets the public ip as DOWN->disconnects  .==>  Setting host 54.1xx.2xx.1xx as DOWN, --disconnecting. My requests are in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The default load balancing policy in the DataStax Node.js Driver for Cassandra is [TokenAwarePolicy with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy as child policy](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/lib/client-options.js#L15).
The DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy is set to use 0 remote nodes by default.

You can change it to use 1 node of each remote datacenter, if the local nodes fail.

```
var localDc = "east1";
var remoteNodes = 1;
var options = { 
  policies: {loadBalancing: new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(localDc, remoteNodes)}
};
var client = new Client(options);
```

Comment: Im still getting the same exception.

Comment: Im able to pass all the requests if my requests are sequential.
But im getting error if i make execute requests in a for loop, im a naive at node.js wanted to test multiple read together